# How to separate the first and last part of a string in a list

Tags: python, string, list

i have the following:

```
a = ['hello there good friend']
```

i need the following:

```
a = ['hello', 'there good', 'friend']
```

Basically I need it so the last index of the list and the first index are separated by commas whereas the rest in between is a single string. I've tried using a for loop for my function, however, it just turned into something really messy which i just think is counter productive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really just be splitting this using the `split()` function and then slicing your results. There might be slightly cleaner ways, but the easiest way I can think of is the following:

```
test = a[0].split()
result = [test[0], " ".join(test[1:-1]), test[-1]]
```

where `-1` represents the last entry of the list.

You could alternately do it in a single line (similar to inspectorG4dget's solution), but it means you're splitting your string three times instead of once.

```
[a[0].split()[0], " ".join(a[0].split()[1:-1]), a[0].split()[-1]]
```

Alternately, if you think that the slicing is a little over the top (which I do), you could use a regular expression instead, which is arguably a much better solution than anything above:

```
import re
a = 'hello there good friend'
return re.split(' (.*) ', a)
>>> ['hello', 'there good', 'friend']
```

As Ord mentions, there's some ambiguity in the question, but for the sample case this should work just fine.

As far as performance goes, gnibbler was right and the regex is in fact slower by about a factor of two, and the complexity of both operations is `O(n)`, so if performance is your goal then you're better of choosing his, but I still think the regex solution is (in a rare win for regex) more readable than the alternatives. Here are the direct timing results:

```
# gnibbler's tuple solution
>>> timeit.timeit("s='hello there good friend';i1=s.find(' ');i2=s.rfind(' ');s[:i1], s[i1+1:i2], s[i2+1:]", number=100000)
0.0976870059967041

# gnibbler's list solution
>>> timeit.timeit("s='hello there good friend';i1=s.find(' ');i2=s.rfind(' ');[s[:i1], s[i1+1:i2], s[i2+1:]]", number=100000)
0.10682892799377441

# my first solution
>>> timeit.timeit("a='hello there good friend'.split();[a[0], ' '.join(a[1:-1]), a[-1]]", number=100000)
0.12330794334411621

# regex solution
>>> timeit.timeit("re.split(' (.*) ', 'hello there good friend')", "import re", number=100000)
0.27667903900146484
```

Comment: Don't you want to concatenate the middle strings? Something like `' '.join(test[1:-1])` ?

Comment: Also, it's not entirely clear what the expected output would be if there were extra spaces between all of the words in the input string, but this solution eats those extra spaces. Not that that's necessarily bad behaviour :)

Comment: @Ord lol, I figured. I posted a solution that's cleaner, and mentioned that the question is a little ambiguous as to what the appropriate response is, but multiple spaces is a little weird.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the last part here. I've deleted my answer (+1)

Comment: @bcorso Lol, no worries, I wasn't saying you should delete your answer.

Comment: I'd suspect the regex will be much slower. Anyone want to run the timings?

Comment: @gnibbler running now, will post in a few.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> [a[0].split(None, 1)[0]] + [a[0].split(None, 1)[-1].rsplit(None, 1)[0]] + [a[0].rsplit(None, 1)[-1]]
['hello', 'there good', 'friend']
```

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic, but this is remarkably unreadable.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: granted. I would advise using intermediate values, like others have done, but I wanted to post this for the sake of completeness - to show that intermediate values are not absolutely necessary

Answer (score 1):

Minimising the creation of temporary strings.

```
>>> a = ['hello there good friend']
>>> s = a[0]
>>> i1 = s.find(' ')
>>> i2 = s.rfind(' ')
>>> s[:i1], s[i1+1:i2], s[i2+1:]
('hello', 'there good', 'friend')     # as a tuple
>>> [s[:i1], s[i1+1:i2], s[i2+1:]]
['hello', 'there good', 'friend']     # as a list
```